# Trying to show text on top of LinearProgress Material Ui/React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this loading bar with max value on the right, progress value on the left:

[image]

And I want to put the text label on top of my LinearProgress bar instead of beside.

Here is my code

```js
      <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
        <Box>
          <Typography>{progressTxt}</Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box width="100%">
          <LinearProgress
            className={classes.root}
            variant="determinate"
            value={100 * (progress / currentMaxTimer)}
            {...props}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <Typography>{currentMaxTimerTxt}</Typography>
        </Box>
      </Box>
```

I'm not quite at ease with the use of Box component, it was on the example I used to start my component.

Comment: Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-payne-sjw1v?file=/src/App.js ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I swear I did my research before posting, but just after posting my answer, I fall in a topic which showed what I want to do with completely differents component, after some twitching, I got this :

```js
      <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <LinearProgress
          className={classes.root}
          variant="determinate"
          value={100 * (progress / currentMaxTimer)}
          {...props}
        />
        <Typography
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            color: "white",
            top: 0,
            left: "5%",
            transform: "translateX(-50%)",
          }}
        >
          {progressTxt}
        </Typography>
        <Typography
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            color: "white",
            top: 0,
            left: "95%",
            transform: "translateX(-50%)",
          }}
        >
          {currentMaxTimerTxt}
        </Typography>
      </div>
```

Which does the trick, even so I don't fully understand what I've done sadly
[progress bar with progress and max value on top of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm5rO.png)

Comment: Yes this does the trick but doesn't look the right way. There should have been a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look into css flexbox as it will make your life so much easier, and you can also avoid  `<Box>` and just use `<div>` or `<Container>`.

HTML:

```
<div class="top"> 
  hi
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <div>
   Progress Bar
  </div>
  <div> 
   53%
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
}

.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
}
```

Just remember to switch `class` with `className` and JSX style for the css.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you means by : "and you can also avoid using and just or ."
Since I use material UI and a boilerplate, I don't really now how to use raw css with it

Comment: Basically you can just wrap your Material UI components in either <div> or <Container> and apply css classes to them. (The div or container)